# How does the Starwood Hotels in-app check-in work for affiliates without a keyless entry system?

Tags: hotels, check-in, starwood

I see that Starwood Properties has been rolling out the In App Check-in and Keyless entry but has not installed them yet at the Westin Brand in Scottsdale.  Was wondering if you can still check-in online via the app to at least save some time when checking in, realizing that you would still have to pick up a physical key.

Comment: Not sure why this has an unclear vote? I don't know the answer, but the question seems clear enough to me. He's just asking if you can use the SPG (Starwood Preferred Guest) app to check-in at the Westin in Scottsdale (Arizona, US) or not, since they don't have the keyless (NFC) entry yet at that property. The question is somewhat localized, but it seems clear enough. I suppose the answer might apply to most or all Starwood properties that don't have the NFC doorlocks, yet, though, so it's not _that_ localized.

Comment: Yes, that was the intent of my question, in this day and age of tech even 2 years past the start of the rollout of the NFC app for key card replacement, I am hoping I can still check-in and save some time in the process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After returning from this property, the answer is no.  They have the NFC card readers on the doors and the keys have the RFID chips in them, but they do not have the Keyless enabled, and therefore you are unable to do an online check-in prior to arrival.  Which in this day and age seems frustrating as we had to wait in line for 20+ minutes to just get our keys.